# Magento 2 - security issues - Before going payment gateway asking credit card

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

On a Magento 2.3.5.p1 website, i used the payment gateway Redsys for credit card payment but before this always loading a credit card screen and seem it is spam and security issue. Can you please help me on this?

[image]

The HTML code i.e. loading as below :

```
<input type="radio" name="payment[method]" class="radio" data-bind="attr: {'id': getCode()}, value: getCode(), checked: isChecked, click: selectPaymentMethod, visible: isRadioButtonVisible()" id="redsys" value="redsys" style="display: none;">
<label data-bind="attr: {'for': getCode()}" class="label" for="redsys"><span data-bind="text: getTitle()">Pago con tarjeta</span></label>
<div class="fieldset customweb-form-V12559531p"><div id="IvTmy"> <dl class="clearfix"><dd><div class="form-list" style=""><li style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><label for="authorizenet_cc_number" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Credit Card Number<span class="required">*</span></label><div class="input-box"><input placeholder="●●●● ●●●● ●●●● ●●●●" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" name="payment[cc_number]" title="Credit Card Number" style="visibility:visible;width:210px;position:inherit;"> </div></li><li style="margin-bottom: 5px;"> <label for="authorizenet_expiration" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Expiration Date<span class="required">*</span></label> <div class="input-box"> <div class="v-fix"><input type="text" name="payment[cc_exp_month]" maxlength="2" style="position:inherit;visibility: visible;width:100px;margin-right: 10px;" class="input-text required-entry" placeholder="MM"><input type="text" name="payment[cc_exp_year]" maxlength="4" style="position:inherit;visibility: visible;width:100px;" class="input-text required-entry" placeholder="YYYY"> </div></div> </li><li style="margin-bottom: 5px;"><label for="authorizenet_cc_cid" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">Card Verification Number<span class="required">*</span></label> <div class="input-box"> <div class="v-fix"><input type="text" style="position:inherit;visibility: visible;width:100px;" maxlength="4" class="input-text required-entry" placeholder="CVC" title="Card Verification Number" name="payment[cc_cid]"></div></div></li> </div></dd> </dl></div></div>
```

See this is the inspect image that may help you more to understand the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved by deleting google tag manager.
I don't know why but it seems that the malicious form is activated with the googler tag manager.